# How do I get lxde desktop to start automatically in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, startup, lxde

One moment my system was fine.  I tried to use Skype and could not get microphone to work.  I tried starting pulseaudio volume control. It would not start. After reboots and a lot of messing about I removed and reinstalled pulseaudio.  Then when I rebooted there was no desktop.  A right click gave me options including terminal and web-browser (I think this is openbox).  I tried 'startlxde' from terminal and was told it was not installed.  I did:

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall lxdm lubuntu-desktop
```

now if I type startlxde in a terminal I get a desktop, albeit completely unlike my old one.  However it does not start automatically.  How can I fix this ?

Also the microphone now works fine, but there is no output sound.  Should I just salvage any personal work and start to install everything from scratch ?

Comment: you could set startlxde to be executed automatically at bootup, that should make the desktop appear as soon as you boot up. I don't know if there's a more elegant solution but reinstalling may be a bit extreme.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the speakers, so now the only thing wrong is not starting lubuntu desktop on boot.  Will installing a greeter package fix that ?

Answer (score 2):

To get the Lubuntu desktop back, I right-clicked in the black openbox desktop and selected logout.  This brought up the greeter screen that I was familiar with.  I had never noticed the buttons in the top right corner before (never needed to use them).  One of these is a pull-down which allows me to select the desktop environment.  Openbox was selected.  I changed the selection to Lubuntu Desktop and logged in as normal.  This gave me the desktop I am used to with all my taskbar customisations intact.

The good thing is that the desktop selection is rememembered.  Subsequent reboots took me straight to Lubuntu desktop instead of Openbox.

Comment: you should click the green check-box to mark this as the correct answer btw